# How to disable past date in owl-date-time picker in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am using owl-date-time picker from angular 5. When I select today date from picker, it should not show past date and month.

Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2 date-right-padding">Date</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5 datePickerField no-left-padding">
   <input [owlDateTime]="createTaskDatePicker" maxlength="19" 
    [disabled]="isDateEnabledCreateTask" 
    [(ngModel)]="createTask.activationDate" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" 
    class="form-control owl-date-time-input" name="createTaskDate" 
    (click)="clearCreateTaskErrorMessages()">
   <owl-date-time #createTaskDatePicker></owl-date-time>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 datePickerIcon">
 </div>
</div>
```

Note:

Past date should be disable, when user select current date.

Question:

How to disable past date in owl-date-time picker.

Your suggestion helpful for me.

Answer (score 8):

- Add current date in component first:

  ```
  public todayDate:any = new Date();
  ```
- Then add below attribute to html input:

  ```
  [min]="todayDate"
  ```

Comment: its woking but if i select current date i am not able to select today date its also disable selected date why?

Comment: @Kapilsoni please check Sukh_Bains answer

Answer (score 4):

You can disable past dates in owl date-time picker like

```
<input [min]="min"
           [owlDateTimeTrigger]="" [owlDateTime]="">
```

Now define min value like this

```
// Min moment: May 10 2018, 10:50
public min = new Date(2018, 4, 10, 10, 50);
```

So it going to disable all dates before May 10 2018.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: its woking but if i select current date i am not able to select today date

Answer (score 4):

The solutions above are correct, but won't work if the user wants to select current date.

```
startAt = new Date();
```

In the constructor set the time to midnight:

```
this.startAt.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Hey, I was struggling with this, thanks for the answer

Comment: in order to have a valid date this is the complete solution:  
    this.startAt.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    this.startAt = this.startAt.toISOString();

Answer (score 3):

IN .ts file

```
minDate = new Date();
```

In .html file

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" [min]="minDate" required [(ngModel)]="createTask.activationDate" name="createTaskDate"  [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt">
<owl-date-time [hour12Timer] = "true" #dt></owl-date-time>
```